# Kotlin's reflection : Unknown type parameter

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I am running some experiments on Kotlin's reflection.

I am trying to get a reflection object of a generic class with its argument.

In Java, that would be a `ParameterizedType`.

The way to get such a thing using Java's reflection API is a bit convoluted: create an anonymous subclass of a generic class, then get its super-type first parameter.

Here's an example:

```
@Suppress("unused") @PublishedApi
internal abstract class TypeReference<T> {}

inline fun <reified T> jGeneric() =
    ((object : TypeReference<T>() {}).javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]
```

When I `println(jGeneric<List<String?>>())`, it prints `java.util.List<? extends java.lang.String>`, which is logical considering that Kotlin's `List` uses declaration-site `out` variance and that Java types have no notion of nullability.

Now, I would like to achieve the same kind of result, but with the Kotlin reflection API (that would, of course, contain nullability information).

Of course, `List<String>::class` cannot work since it yields a `KClass`. and I am looking for a `KType`.

However, when I try this:

```
inline fun <reified T> kGeneric() =
    (object : TypeReference<T>() {})::class.supertypes[0].arguments[0].type
```

When I `println(kGeneric<List<String?>>())`, it prints `[ERROR : Unknown type parameter 0]`, which is quite... well, anticlimactic ;)

How can I get, in Kotlin, a `KType` reflecting `List<String>` ?

Comment: The "`[ERROR : ...]`" part is a bug in the `toString` implementation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17103

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To create a `KType` instance in Kotlin 1.1, you have two options:

- To create a simple non-nullable type out of a `KClass`, where the class is either not generic or you can substitute all its type parameters with star projections (`*`), use the `starProjectedType` property. For example, the following creates a `KType` representing a non-nullable type `String`:

  ```
  val nonNullStringType = String::class.starProjectedType
  ```

  Or, the following creates a `KType` representing a non-nullable type `List<*>`:

  ```
  val nonNullListOfSmth = List::class.starProjectedType
  ```
- For more complex cases, use the `createType` function. It takes the class, type arguments and whether or not the type should be nullable. Type arguments are a list of `KTypeProjection` which is simply a type + variance (in/out/none). For example, the following code creates a `KType` instance representing `List<String>`:

  ```
  val nonNullStringType = String::class.starProjectedType
  val projection = KTypeProjection.invariant(nonNullStringType)
  val listOfStrings = listClass.createType(listOf(projection))
  ```

  Or, the following creates the type `List<String>?`:

  ```
  val listOfStrings = listClass.createType(listOf(projection), nullable = true)
  ```

Both `starProjectedType` and `createType` are defined in package `kotlin.reflect.full`.

[We're planning](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15992) to introduce the possibility of getting a `KType` instance simply from a reified type parameter of an inline function which would help in some cases where the needed type is known statically, however currently it's not entirely clear if that's possible without major overhead. So, until that's implemented, please use the declarations explained above.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer forces the manual creation of the type, which makes it a no-go for library usage.
I'll be watching the issue you linked... Thanks ;)

Comment: And I think also in 1.1 the creation of a type like above cannot be used in all cases, there are some aspects that were not implemented.  `defaultType` was still required to work around these errors.  Maybe @udalov can comment on that being resolved.

Comment: @JaysonMinard what errors and aspects specifically do you mean?