# How to get the KClass for a Kotlin constructor parameter

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Using Kotlin reflection, I am trying to check the KClass of each parameter of a class's primary constructor.

Given a simple data class like this:

```
data class MyPerson(val name: String, val age: Int)
val modelClass = MyPerson::class
```

I get its primary constructor `val primaryConstructor = modelClass.primaryConstructor`.
For each parameter, I want to check its class (is it Kotlin.String, Kotlin.Int etc). Something like this:

```
for (param in primaryConstructor.parameters) {
  when(param.type) {
    is Kotlin.String -> // do string thing
    is Kotlin.Int -> // do int thing
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't valid code. I've tried `param.type`, `param.classifier`, `param.type.jvmErasure` and others. The closest I've found is `param.type.jvmErasure.qualifiedName`, which gives me a String with the fully qualified name of the KClass. But I really want the KClass.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`javaType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/java-type.html) property of `KType` for that comparison:

```
when (param.type.javaType) {
    String::class.java -> println("String!")
    Int::class.java -> println("Int!")
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The `param.type` expression returns a [`KType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/index.html), so you need to [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862966/how-to-obtain-a-ktype-in-kotlin) the appropriate `Ktype` instances to check against:

```
for (param in primaryConstructor.parameters) {
    when (param.type) {
        String::class.createType() -> println("String param")
        Int::class.createType() -> println("Int param")
    }
}
```

---

Side note: might be a good idea to not create these every time in the loop:

```
val stringType = String::class.createType()
val intType = Int::class.createType()
for (param in primaryConstructor.parameters) {
    when (param.type) {
        stringType -> println("String param")
        intType -> println("Int param")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the unsafe cast operator `as`:

```
val kClass: KClass<*> = param.type.classifier as KClass<*>
```